# Replacement has 0 rows, data has 1400?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I checked the other questions and couldn't really find the solution.

I'm trying to update a vector in my dataframe based on a BUNCH of conditionals like the following:

```
EEG3$CorrectFinal <-as.character(EEG3$CorrectFinal)
subjectlist1 = c("s002","s004","s010","s011","s012","s017","s018","s019","s020","s025","s026","s028")
for (i in subjectlist1) {
EEG3$CorrectFinal <- ifelse (EEG3$subject == subjectlist1[i] & EEG3$trial <326 & EEG3$Deviant == 101 & EEG3$Correct == 222|EEG$subject == subjectlist1[i] & EEG3$trial <326 & EEG3$Deviant == 102 & EEG3$Correct == 155|EEG3$subject  == subjectlist1[i] & EEG3$trial >326 & EEG3$Deviant == 101 & EEG3$Correct == 155|EEG$subject == subjectlist1[i] & EEG3$trial >326 & EEG3$Deviant == 102 & EEG3$Correct == 222, yes = 1, no = EEG3$CorrectFinal)}
```

But then I get the following error message:
`` Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "CorrectFinal", value = logical(0)) :  replacement has 0 rows, data has 20 ``

So I've created an vector (column) of zeroes in the data frame, and assign the conditionals to either, if true, populate with a 1, if not, keep the same value (which is a 0). I just don't understand why I'm getting this error message, or where this script is breaking.

Here's some code to reproduce the problem with an example data frame:

````
EEG3 <-read.table(header = TRUE, text ="  subject trial Deviant Correct CorrectFinal
1     s002     1     101     102            0
                    2     s002     2     102     101            0
                    3     s002     3     101     155            0
                    4     s002     4     101     155            0
                    5     s002     5     101     155            0
                    6     s002     6     101     155            0
                    7     s002     7     102     222            0
                    8     s002     8     101     155            0
                    9     s002     9     101     155            0
                    10    s002    10     102     222            0
                    11    s002    11     101     222            1
                    12    s002    12     101     222            1
                    13    s002    13     101     222            1
                    14    s002    14     101     222            1
                    15    s002    15     102     155            1
                    16    s002    16     101     222            1
                    17    s002    17     101     155            0
                    18    s002    18     101     222            1
                    19    s002    19     102     155            1
                    20    s002    20     101     222            1")

> ```
````

Comment: Is `mydata` supposed to be `EEG3`?

Comment: Incidentally, are you ignoring `trial` of `326`? Your logic ensures it is never matched.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code does not error on my console, but there is a problem that might be contributing to issues on your end.

Step through your code in your loop. Using `mydata` as `EEG3`, if you step into your `for` loop,

```r
for (i in subjectlist1) {
  message(sprintf("i='%s', subjectlist1[i]='%s'", i, subjectlist1[i]))
  EEG3$CorrectFinal <- ifelse ( ... )    
}
```

You'll see right away that the first message is `i='s002', subjectlist1[i]='NA'` ...

Your `for` loop is iterating over actual values, not indices on the vector `subjectlist1`.

Use one of the following two models:

1. `for (i in seq_along(subjectlist1))` and keep the rest of your code, since `i` will now be an integer; or
2. `for (i in subjectlist1)` and change all inner `subjectlist1[i]` to `i`, since `i` will be a string.

Side note: the order of your logic might not be what you need. Whenever I start nesting `&` and `|`, I'll use parens to lock-in the actual logic I need. For instance, I infer you need something like:

```t
for (i in subjectlist1) {
  EEG3$CorrectFinal <- 
    ifelse (
      EEG3$subject == subjectlist1[i] & (
        (EEG3$trial < 326 & EEG3$Deviant == 101 & EEG3$Correct == 222) |
        (EEG3$trial < 326 & EEG3$Deviant == 102 & EEG3$Correct == 155) |
        (EEG3$trial > 326 & EEG3$Deviant == 101 & EEG3$Correct == 155) |
        (EEG3$trial > 326 & EEG3$Deviant == 102 & EEG3$Correct == 222)
      ), yes = 1, no = EEG3$CorrectFinal)
}
```

This can actually be simplified a bit, removing the need for a `for` loop altogether.

Your code first, then mine:

```r
# this is just to prepopulate the CorrectFinal2 variable to compare your for loop with my code
EEG3$CorrectFinal2 <- EEG3$CorrectFinal

# your code, adjusted
for (i in seq_along(subjectlist1)) {
  EEG3$CorrectFinal <- 
    ifelse (
      EEG3$subject == subjectlist1[i] & (
        (EEG3$trial < 326 & EEG3$Deviant == 101 & EEG3$Correct == 222) |
        (EEG3$trial < 326 & EEG3$Deviant == 102 & EEG3$Correct == 155) |
        (EEG3$trial > 326 & EEG3$Deviant == 101 & EEG3$Correct == 155) |
        (EEG3$trial > 326 & EEG3$Deviant == 102 & EEG3$Correct == 222)
      ), yes = 1, no = EEG3$CorrectFinal)
}
ind <- with(EEG3, {
  subject %in% subjectlist1 & (
    (trial < 326 & Deviant == 101 & Correct == 222) |
    (trial < 326 & Deviant == 102 & Correct == 155) |
    (trial > 326 & Deviant == 101 & Correct == 155) |
    (trial > 326 & Deviant == 102 & Correct == 222))
})
EEG3$CorrectFinal2[ind] <- 1

EEG3
#    subject trial Deviant Correct CorrectFinal CorrectFinal2
# 1     s002     1     101     102            0             0
# 2     s002     2     102     101            0             0
# 3     s002     3     101     155            0             0
# 4     s002     4     101     155            0             0
# 5     s002     5     101     155            0             0
# 6     s002     6     101     155            0             0
# 7     s002     7     102     222            0             0
# 8     s002     8     101     155            0             0
# 9     s002     9     101     155            0             0
# 10    s002    10     102     222            0             0
# 11    s002    11     101     222            1             1
# 12    s002    12     101     222            1             1
# 13    s002    13     101     222            1             1
# 14    s002    14     101     222            1             1
# 15    s002    15     102     155            1             1
# 16    s002    16     101     222            1             1
# 17    s002    17     101     155            0             0
# 18    s002    18     101     222            1             1
# 19    s002    19     102     155            1             1
# 20    s002    20     101     222            1             1
```

(And I argue that parens, indentation, reduction of logic components, and no `for` loop make it a little more readable.)